# How to generate a very large non singular matrix A in Ax = b?

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra

I am solving the system of linear algebraic equations Ax = b by using Jacobian method but by taking manual inputs. I want to analyze the performance of the solver for large system. Is there any method to generate matrix A i.e non singular?
I am attaching my code here.`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define TOL = 0.0001

void main()
{
  int size,i,j,k = 0;
  printf("\n enter the number of equations: ");
  scanf("%d",&size);
  double reci = 0.0;
  double *x = (double *)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
  double *x_old = (double *)malloc(size*sizeof(double));

  double *b = (double *)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
  double *coeffMat = (double *)malloc(size*size*sizeof(double));

  printf("\n Enter the coefficient matrix: \n");

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
      printf(" coeffMat[%d][%d] = ",i,j);
      scanf("%lf",&coeffMat[i*size+j]);
      printf("\n");
      //coeffMat[i*size+j] = 1.0;
    }
  }

  printf("\n Enter the b vector: \n");

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    x[i] = 0.0;
    printf(" b[%d] = ",i);
    scanf("%lf",&b[i]);    
  }

  double sum = 0.0;

  while(k < size)
  {

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      x_old[i] = x[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      sum = 0.0;
      for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
      {
        if(i != j)
        {
          sum += (coeffMat[i * size + j] * x_old[j] );
        }
      }

      x[i] = (b[i] -sum) / coeffMat[i * size + i];

    }

    k = k+1;
  }

  printf("\n Solution is: ");

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf(" x[%d] = %lf \n ",i,x[i]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1991/CSD-91-658.pdf - I think this is what the Linpack benchmark uses.

Comment: Your solver should be able to detect singularity, and singular matrices should be a part of the test suite.

Comment: Thanks. I am having other question, How can we check solution for random matrix whether it is correct or wrong?

Comment: You should **edit your question** to ask that, or ask another question... Don't improve your own question in comments, but by editing it.

Comment: I would start by a diagonal all-ones matrix( := identity), and apply some (a lot!) random rotations on it. (you could consider this the *reversed Jacobi method*)

Answer (score 1):

This is all a bit Heath Robinson, but here's what I've used. I have no idea how 'random' such matrices all, in particular I don't know what distribution they follow.

The idea is to generate the SVD of the matrix. (Called A below, and assumed nxn).

Initialise A to all 0s

Then generate n positive numbers, and put them, with random signs,  in the diagonal of A. I've found it useful to be able to control the ratio of the largest of these positive numbers to the smallest. This ratio will be the condition number of the matrix.

Then repeat n times: generate a random n vector f , and multiply A on the left by the Householder reflector I - 2*f*f' / (f'*f). Note that this can be done more efficiently than by forming the reflector matrix and doing a normal multiplication; indeed its easy to write a routine that given f and A will update A in place.

Repeat the above but multiplying on the right.

As for generating test data a simple way is to pick an x0 and then generate  b = A * x0. Don't expect to get exactly x0 back from your solver; even if it is remarkably well behaved you'll find that the errors get bigger as the condition number gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

[Talonmies'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) comment mentions http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1991/CSD-91-658.pdf which is probably the right approach (at least in principle, and in full generality).

However, you are probably *not* handling "very large" matrixes (e.g. because your program use naive algorithms, and because you don't run it on a large supercomputer with a lot of RAM). So the naive approach of generating a matrix with random coefficients and testing afterwards that it is non-singular is probably enough.

Very large matrixes would have many billions of coefficients, and you need a powerful supercomputer with e.g. terabytes of RAM. You probably don't have that, if you did, your program probably would run too long (you don't have any parallelism), might give very wrong results (read http://floating-point-gui.de/ for more) so you don't care.

A matrix of a million coefficients (e.g. 1024*1024) is considered *small* by current hardware standards (and is more than enough to test your code on current laptops or desktops, and even to test some parallel implementations), and generating randomly some of them (and computing their determinant to test that they are not singular) is enough, and easily doable. You might even generate them and/or check their regularity with some *external* tool, e.g. [scilab](http://scilab.org/), [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), etc. Once your program computed a solution *x<sub>0</sub>*, you could use some tool (or write another program) to compute *Ax<sub>0</sub> - b* and check that it is very close to the 0 vector (there are some cases where you would be disappointed or surprised, since [round-off errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) matter).

You'll need some good enough [pseudo random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) perhaps as simple as [drand48(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html) which is considered as nearly obsolete (you should find and use something better); you could seed it with some random source (e.g. `/dev/urandom` on Linux).

BTW, compile your code with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Your `#define TOL = 0.0001` is probably wrong (should be `#define TOL 0.0001` or `const double tol = 0.0001;`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Add optimizations (`-O2 -mcpu=native`) when benchmarking. Read the documentation of every used function, notably those from [`<stdio.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Check the result count from `scanf`... In C99, you should not cast the result of `malloc`, but you forgot to test against its failure, so code:

```
double *b = malloc(size*sizeof(double));
if (!b) {perror("malloc b"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You'll rather end, not start, your `printf` control strings with `\n` because `stdout`  is often (not always!) line buffered. See also `fflush`.

You probably should read also some basic linear algebra textbook...

Notice that actually writing robust and efficient programs to invert matrixes or to solve linear systems is a difficult art (which I don't know at all : it has programming issues, algorithmic issues, and mathematical issues; read some [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) book). You can still get a PhD and spend your whole life working on that. Please understand that you need [ten years to learn programming](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) (or many other things).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I have uploaded a partial code without tolerance criteria etc.. I want to convert this program into any parallel programming languages, so i need  sufficiently large matrix to analyze the speedup. Though we take a random matrix but still how can we check answer whether correct or wrong?